# Pushing new codebase to an existing repo's branch

Tags: git, github

I have two codebases.

- One made in Flutter, and
- one in React Native.

The Flutter project is on GitHub under `user/flutter`, but the React Native project isn't (not even version controlled).

Is there a way I can push the react native code to a new branch on `user/flutter` without messing up any of the code?

I want to keep the original structure of the flutter app.

Comment: Is there a reason they need to be in the same repo? Do they share anything / have any overlap?

Comment: well not necessarily but I would prefer yes

Comment: Can you give a reason? Because it's really not a good idea, and introduces dev inconveniences -- e.g. you will be hard to work on both at the same time. Please add the reasons to your question.

Comment: Well, I want to keep the original structure of the flutter app.

Comment: Then please update your question with more detail. Because what you just seemed to describe is not "two codebases", but two versions of the same codebase, some parts in common, some parts divergent. One can't give a proper answer without knowing this stuff.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the technologies mentioned over the tags as this is 100% a git question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an [orphan branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---orphanltnew-branchgt), add and commit the code there, then push.

```
git switch --orphan newBranch
```

You would have in effect two codebase in one repository, which might or might not be a good idea, but a concurrent development can occur on both branches.

The [OP Inigo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8910547/inigo) adds however in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236646/pushing-new-codebase-to-an-existing-repos-branch/68236722?noredirect=1#comment120599051_68236722):

> I think these are not "two codebases" but one diverging one.
>
> In which case I'd have him:
>
> - make a new branch,
> - replace the worktree content with his React version, then
> - check it in, which would result in a commit that represented the differences

Comment: I had that in mind too, Von, but based on his replies to my questions above, I think these are not "two codebases" but one diverging one. In which case I'd have him make a new branch, replace the worktree content with his React version, then check it in, which would result in a commit that represented the differences. The ask otherwise doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Inigo Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.